# IE6 border-bottom: 0 & padding CSS issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, border, padding

I just encountered a IE6 bug that I don't seem to identify over the net.

Basically this is when the behavior is triggered: a block element has border, on all sides except bottom, and top/bottom padding. and inside it there's another block element.

My entire code is to big to fit in here, but I narrowed it down to this simple example:

```
<div style="border: 5px solid red; border-bottom: 0; padding: 5px;">
    <p>adasasasdas</p>
</div>
Following stuff
```

Now the thing that goes wrong is that the "Following stuff"'s position (whatever that is), will be altered weirdly. In this case a few pixels to the left.

To disable that weird behavior I can either keep the bottom border, get rid of the padding or make the contained element inline. But I kinda want them both. Before I have to give them up, I wanted to see if there is knowledge about this bug and if there is an alternative fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good fix to the bug:

```
<div style="border: 5px solid red; border-bottom: 0; padding: 5px; font-size:0">
    <p style="font-size:16">adasasasdas</p>&nbsp
</div>
Following stuff
```

Basically, there has to be some inline text at the end of the div for IE6 to render it correctly.  Since the &nbsp added an extra line to the bottom, I changed the font size to 0 in the `div`, then back to 16 (or whatever you'd normally use) inside the `<p>`.  This has a very minimal effect on the height of the div (about 2 pixels in all major browsers) but it shouldn't be at all noticeable to users.  Alternatively, you can try altering the `line-height` variable to 0% in the `div`, then back to 100% in the `p`, but that seemed to change the `div`'s height by a few more pixels than the `font-size` method when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

My fix would be

```
<div style="border: 5px solid red; padding: 5px; padding-bottom:4px; border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
    <p>adasasasdas</p>
</div>
Following stuff
```

but that may not be applicable for you depending on the context

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

`<div style="border-left: 5px solid red; border-top: 5px solid red; padding: 0px;">
    <p style="margin:0px; padding:10px;">adasasasdas</p>
</div>
Following stuff`

If you want padding adjust padding in `<p>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I know this is old, but I also just spent several hours fighting with this bug (and in fact it took me this long to figure out that it was because of border-bottom + padding-bottom...which is a shame because if I knew what to search for I would've found this much sooner).

Anyway it suddenly occurred to me that this is yet another manifestation of the hasLayout issue in ie6. For my purposes, adding "zoom:1" to the offending divs suddenly and magically fixed it, which has the benefit of not fussing with font sizes and line heights and such.